# onActivityForResult not called on orientation change

Tags: android, save, android-activity, android-camera, android-orientation

I've been trying to start an camera activity from my app, to take and save a photo that will later be upploaded.
I use this code to start the camera and save the file:

```
public Bitmap photo;  //the var the captured picture gets saved in.

//Inside the onCreate.
cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
    }
});

//The onActivityResult
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    //Gets the photo
    photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
} 


//this is called from the donebutton's onClickListener
protected void savePicture(String name, Bitmap picture)
{
    try
    { 
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream( Menu.savePath + TransServActivity.fileName + "/" + name + "Problem.png");
        picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fOut);
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Puts the error in an error log.
        //TODO put in error log
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The Activity is locked in portrait orientation in the Manifest.xml and the code works like a charm if you capture and save the photo in portrait. 
But if you capture and save the photo while the device is in landscape orientation, this activity restars in landscape-mode and then get's forced in to portrait.

This makes the variable that I save the Bitmap in become null and not get saved when you click the done button. And I'm not even sure if the onActivityResult() gets called.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks alot, i appreciate any help i can get //David

Comment: onRestoreInstanceState is called when orientation changes and not the onActivityResult.

Comment: Yeah but the "startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);"
calles the onActivityResult after capturing the photo.
How can i save an image from the "startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);" from the onRestoreInstanceState?

Comment: you have to save image into onSaveInstanceState() and get image from onRestoreInstanceState().

Comment: check this question and its answer, perhaps it will solve your issue http://stackoverflow.com/q/11065574/582571

Comment: Thank you, got it to work!

This is my first android application and i haven't gotten to use SaveInstanceState before. and i had no idé that you could save bitmaps in it.

I'm sorry if I wasted your time with this question, but i've been checking stackoverflow for ages and didn't find an awnser for this.

Comment: @kamden I suggest to never save bitmaps on bundles such as in this case. Instead put in cache or on a static reference that will be carefully removed when done using it. The reason is that bitmaps are quite heavy on memory and to be put into bundles.